# How to make a web browser for Android platform?

Tags: android, webkit

I want to make a web browser to handle a network packet.

Is it possible to customize a default web browser?

I tried to find the way to modify webkit source,

but it is hard to make it because it's not simple java code.

Anyone knows about it?

Help me Please!

Comment: Yes, it is hard to modify a browser.  It's not impossible, but you haven't demonstrated that you've made much effort.  You could start by figuring out which language WebKit is written in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webview. Download the data and feed it to the webview.

Comment: It it possible to control a network packet? i want to encrypt a network packet for security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the standards. Use SSL/TLS for encryption.